# How do you change an attribute in Weka to Datetime

Tags: dataset, weka, preprocessor

8.3 to do some data cleaning and modeling. I'm working off [this UFO sighting data](https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/ufo-sightings-around-the-world) all other attributes imported as intended, however the Date_time does not change to datetime attribute when changed during importing or when using any of the date related pre-processing filters.

I tried changing the date format:

[image: ChangeDateFormat]

But that doesn't seem to work and during the import change I get with changing the format to `dd-MM-yyyy'HH:mm`

I get this error dialogue:

[image]

I'd like to clarify that i'm using only the first 5000 instances of the 800000+ in the original file.

I've also taken a look at the other two Stack overflow weka datetime questions but they haven't provide any more help [this link](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) from one of them was supposed to be the answer to my issues but has not really answered why I can't get mine to work, any help would be appreciated